# Insert an Updated Row to an ASP .Net GridView

Tags: asp.net

I am updating a GridView dataRow on GridView_RowUpdating event and Updating the database too.
on GridView_RowUpdating event i wrote c# code to update the database and after successfull update of database i am creating a class object of this row. and trying to bind this row to another grid.

Database is getting updated but another grid is not being updated.

Any Solution??

Here is my code

```
Grid_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
  // Update Operation for First Grid  
  ...
  ...

  Class1 ObjRow = new Class1();
  ObjRow.Status = Updated.


  List<Class1> lst = GetUpdatedDetails();
  GridView1.DataSource = lst;
  GridView1.DataBind();


  lst = new List<Class1>();
  lst.add(ObjRow)


  // Here Its Failing
  GridView2.DataSource = lst;
  GridView2.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: _"i wrote c# code"_ So why don't you show it us? A glance in the crystal ball reveals that you've forgotten to call `GridView2.DataBind()`.

Comment: What does _"Here Its Failing"_ mean? Do you get an exception(maybe in `RowDataBound`), have you debugged it? Why are you using the variable `lst` for two different things? That is at least confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Is the second Gridview in an UpdatePanel? Try adding the new row then refreshing the Page. Doe s this have any effect?

Comment: Both the Grids are in UpdatePanel.

Comment: Are both of their UpdateModes set to always?

Comment: When you say 'Here it's failing' what do you mean? Are you getting an exception? If so could you post it's details please.

Comment: No i am not getting any exception. 'Here it's failing' means that GridView2 is not getting bind (Row is not visible in the GridView2)

Comment: Maybe try putting a break point in the code after lst.add(ObjRow) and step to see whether lst actually contains ObjRow.